# as much / many as + countable plurals

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns

I am wondering whether "much" or "many" should be used in the following sentence:

> it's unusual that people as **much / many** as four generations apart speak to each other in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's ambiguous. It depends on how you are interpreting the meaning of *four generations apart*—on what you are emphasizing.

---

> ✔ I have read as **many** *books* as you.
>   ✘ I have read as **much** *books* as you.

Here, *books* is countable (and plural), so we use *many*.

> ✘ I have read as **many** *of the book* as you.
>   ✘ I have read as **much** *of the book* as you.

Here, *book* is singular and not being counted per se. So, we treat it as a single, indivisible thing—even though it is still *measurable*.

---

> ✔ I cut off as **much** as *a four-foot length* of rope.

Here, *a four-foot length* is being treated as a single thing, despite the fact that *four* is part of the noun phrase. It's treated in the same way as this:

> ✔ I drank as **much** as *one cup of water*.

---

> ✔ I cut off as **many** as *four foot-long pieces* of rope.

Here, *four* is counting the number of *foot-long pieces*—and the total is divisible rather than just measured.

---

So, returning to the actual sentence in the question, it depends on how you parse the phrase *four generations apart*.

> ✔ I cut off as **much** as (*a four-foot length*) of rope.
>
> → ✔ It's unusual that people as **much** as *(four generations apart)* speak to each other in the same way.

Here, *four generations apart* is treated as a single thing: a measure of time that spans four generations.

But:

> ✔ I cut off as **many** as *four (foot-long pieces)* of rope.
>
> → ✔ It's unusual that people as **many** as *four (generations apart)* speak to each other in the same way.

Here, the number of generations are actually being counted individually rather than being used as a description of a *single* length of time that has lasted four generations.

---

The syntax of the noun phrase on its own doesn't *force* one or the other interpretation. It depends largely on the broader context—and where you want to put the emphasis.

Note that in originally thinking about this, I had a personal intuition that it should really only be one of these interpretations (I won't say which one). But after analyzing this, I realized that was merely an initial reaction on my part. Even if somebody would be personally inclined to always interpret it one way, that doesn't mean that somebody else wouldn't interpret it the other way. In this sentence, both versions are grammatical.